# Storing in a global variable using inline assembly

Tags: avr, assembly, avr-toolchain

What I'm trying to do is pretty basic: I have a global variable and I'm trying to store some value in it (specifically, the SP_H and SP_L values).

The variable is an array of structs and I'm trying to access one of those structs.

This is what I am doing:

```
typedef struct_t { uint8_t sp_h, sp_l; } struct_t;    

struct_t arr[MAX_STRUCTS];

void some_inline_assembly_function()
{
  volatile asm(

  // Determine where to store the new SP_H and SP_L register

  "lds r26, ???                \n\t" // <-- How do I store the address
                                            of arr[0].sp_h or arr[0].sp_l
                                            in the X registers (r26,27)
  "lds r27, ???                \n\t"

  // This part stores the stack pointer low and high byte indirectly
     using the X registers (r26,27), which is what I want.

  "in    r0, __SP_L__          \n\t" 
  "st    x+, r0                \n\t" 
  "in    r0, __SP_H__          \n\t"
  "st    x+, r0                \n\t"
  ::);
}
```

If this looks familiar, it is because it probably is. I'm trying to implement simple context switching (pushing the entire task context into the stack and retrieving another one). What I'm trying to accomplish is storing the current PC_H and PC_L to a global variable so that the "shceduler" knows where to start popping the registers and restore the context.

Yes, I know FreeRTOS does this. I need to know how to do this myself.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Did you try to just use `arr` in the assembly?

Comment: I've just seen people pop the registers onto the stack in a particular order, and then change the stack pointer(s) to another stack.

Comment: Probably a stupid idea, but why not write it in C, compile it, and run `avr-objdump -S ` against the elf file, and see how the C compiler does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address you are looking for is a symbol known by the linker. Then
you can have the linker put the *value* of the symbol straight into your
code: no need to load from memory. In other words, you use the `ldi`
instruction to load the required address as an *immediate* value. You
should also reverse the order of the struct definition, since you are
storing SPL at the lowest address.

```c
typedef struct { uint8_t sp_l, sp_h; } struct_t;    

struct_t arr[MAX_STRUCTS];

void some_inline_assembly_function()
{
  asm volatile(
    // Determine where to store the new SP_H and SP_L register
    "ldi r26, lo8(arr)     \n\t"  // X is loaded with the symbol arr
    "ldi r27, hi8(arr)     \n\t"  // which is the address of arr[0].sp_l
    // Here you may want to add 2 * an array index.

    // This part stores the stack pointer low and high byte indirectly
    // using the X registers (r26,27), which is what I want.
    "in    r0, __SP_L__    \n\t" 
    "st    x+, r0          \n\t" 
    "in    r0, __SP_H__    \n\t"
    "st    x+, r0          \n\t"
  ::);
}
```

Notice the `lo8()` and `hi8()` assembler macros: they split the address
into low and high bytes. Actually the assembler translates them into
R_AVR_LO8_LDI and R_AVR_HI8_LDI relocations records, and the
linker does the real job.

**Edit**: I think I just realized why you were thinking of using `lds`
in the first place...

Instead of using array indices, you may want to access the array through
a pointer (declared `struct_t *pointer`). When programming in C or C++,
a pointer identifier behaves, for most purposes, just like an array
identifier. However, at the assembly level, using a pointer involves an
extra indirection, as you have to read the contents of the pointer from
RAM. In this case you would indeed be using `lds` instructions:

```
; Copy the global 'pointer' into the X pointer register.
lds r26, pointer    ; low byte
lds r27, pointer+1  ; high byte
```

As a side note, if you are programming in C++, then you have to declare
`extern "C"` any identifier that you want to use both in C++ and in
assembly. Otherwise the C++ compiler will
[mangle its name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and you
would need to use the mangled name in the assembly source.